# Find similarities between two lists

Tags: performance

I have two lists of numbers (L1 and L2). And I have to find whether any combination of L1 is in any combination of L2 numbers.

I have tried a double loop through a powerset() function. However it is slowly.

powerset() generator: technomancy.org/python/powerset-generator-python.

I don't post the code as what I need is some ideas, approaches or whatever could iluminate me.

Extra problem: ListA could be a monster list in terms of length and range of the numbers

Comment: lookup "knapsack problem" / "divide & conquer" algorithms

Comment: Also look at a technique called Dynamic Programming.

Comment: You have a float and a negative number in `listA`; is this correct?  Allowing floats makes the accuracy a problem; allowing negative numbers removes many optimizations.

Comment: If you have only positive numbers, you can prune a search branch as soon as you've passed the target value.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the lists can contain floating point numbers. Because, for example, the python code `a=0.1 b=0.2 c=0.3 if (a+b==c): print 'Y' else: print 'N'` will print `N`.

Comment: Hi user33... try this code please, `a=[1.3, -0.2, -1.1]  if sum(a) == 0:  print ('Y' ) else: print ('N')` it returns Y. I am completly sure that my data is composed by pos/neg floating point numbers. And the algo is woking with the limitation of comparing N to N large subsets.

Comment: Indeed you'll need something like this `listA=[0.1,-0.2] listB=[1.4,-1.5] if (sum(listA)==sum(listB)): print 'Y' else: print 'N'` which prints `N` when it should print `Y`

Comment: I haven't figured out solution yet, but one thing is sure: Since `1:N` case for all positive numbers is an `np complete`, this should also be an `np complete` (or rather an `np hard` if we go by definition). So you cannot expect a polynomial time solution for this. May be pseudo polynomial time as exists for `1:N`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the dynamic programming approach.  If you have integers it will work well.  The win here is that you only track one way to get to any particular sum, which means that your performance is bounded by the number of sums.

```
def all_sums (numbers):
    answer = {0: None}
    for n in numbers:
        next_answer = {}
        for s, path in answer.iteritems():
            next_answer[s] = path
            next_answer[round(s + n, 8)] = [n, path]
        answer = next_answer
    if answer[0] is None:
        answer.pop(0)
    return answer

def find_matching_sum (numbers1, numbers2):
    sums1 = all_sums(numbers1)
    sums2 = all_sums(numbers2)
    for s1, path1 in sums1.iteritems():
        if s1 in sums2:
            return [s1, path1, sums2[s1]]
    return None

listA = [455, 698, 756, 3.56, -9]

listB = [526,55,943,156,531,304,618,911,598,498,268,926,899,898,131,966,303,936,509,67,976,639,74,935,23,226,422,280,64,975,583,596,583]
print(find_matching_sum(listA, listB))
```

With floating point, I would suggest trying to multiply by a common denominator to get to integers.  This is to deal with the `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` problem.  Also be aware that with floating point it is easy to have a very, very large number of possible sums, and so the dynamic programming approach is no longer a win.  For an extreme example consider `[..., 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, ...]` and now the whole powerset comes out to play...

Answer (score 1):

If you are still in the region where it is feasable to generate full powersets (and we dont have to try to work around that), then you can simply sort the powersets (by the value of their sum) and compare them in order, the same way you would in mergesort. This would reduce the runtime from `O(2^N * 2*M)` to `O(2^N + 2^M)`, still not nice, but it does reduce the effective problem size from `O(N+M)` to `O(max(N,M)`.

Comment: Note that sorting is O(nlogn) so at the end you get a complexity O(N 2^N)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but you can actually extend coin change approach which you did for your subcases 2 and 3 mentioned in the OP. The idea here is to utilize the memoization table which you create in the dynamic programming approach. Please note that you need to have positive numbers (can be floats) in both arrays to get the best possible solution here.

Consider two arrays: 
`[4,3,5,1]` and `[2,6,4,3]`

Lets create the memoization table for first array using coin change approach, where the maximum sum you want is the sum of all the elements of an array, which in this case is 13. The memoization table looks like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
4   T   F   F   F   T   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F
3   T   F   F   T   T   F   F   T   F   F   F   F   F   F
5   T   F   F   T   T   T   F   T   T   T   F   F   T   F
1   T   T   F   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   F   T   T
```

For the second array, total sum is 15 and the table looks like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
2   T   F   T   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F
6   T   F   T   F   F   F   T   F   T   F   F   F   F   F   F   F
4   T   F   T   F   T   F   T   F   T   F   T   F   T   F   F   F
3   T   F   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   F   T
```

If you see last row of both the tables, you can easily conclude that whichever column have value as T, that particular column number can be expressed as a sum of some elements in the given array. And how do you find those elements? You simple backtrack in the existing memoization table for all possible ways to get that particular column sum. Start from the last row for any column that has the cell value as `T`. Then you can backtrack using for all values of T for that particular column and adjusting your sum accordingly.

Moving to main part now about how do you know which subsequence gives you same sum. Case 4 of OP. Well, once you had form the above subsequences for all sums possible using the last row, you can just compare the last row of both memoization tables, column by column, to find which sums are actually formed in both the arrays and return the associated subsequences stored against those sums. For example in this case of given two arrays, the common sums formed by above two array elements would be `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13]` and using the approach discussed above, you can map these sums against List of arrays giving these sums and hence return those arrays as result.

Time complexity in this would be `O(n1*s1 + n2*s2)`
where `ni` and `si` are number and sum of the elements in array `ai` as I think you can extend this approach for `k` given arrays as well.

Please let me know if anyone finds any flaw here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much better approach than my previous answer (which I deleted). This solution uses a subset sum function (iSubSumIndexes) that returns indices rather than values.  The common sum search works by merging the two lists after inverting elements in one of them. Then, seeking a subset sum of zero in the combined list will produce a combined set of elements from the two lists that form a common sum. Elements that make up the zero-sum can then be separated in two sets based on their list or origin.

The subset sum function (iSubSumIndexes) uses a better approach than my previous answer. This new algorithm is much less prone to "worst case" patterns. It is just as fast if not faster than the old one (i.e. sub second response for 100 item lists):

```
from bisect import bisect_right
from itertools import accumulate
def iSubSumIndexes(S,A,maxSize=None):
    smallSize     = 20
    smallSums     = set()
    def subSumForSize(S,A,size,failedSums=None):
        nextSum = A[size-2][2] if size>1 else 0
        index   = bisect_right([a for a,_,_ in A],S-nextSum) # max element for target
        A       = A[:index]
        if len(A) < size:    return                  # not enough elements for size
        if A[size-1][2]  > S: return                 # minimum sum > target
        maxSum = A[-1][2]
        if len(A) > size: maxSum -= A[-size-1][2]
        if maxSum < S:  return                       # maximum sum < target
        if len(A) <= smallSize and S not in smallSums: return

        if failedSums is None: failedSums = set()

        while index >= size: 
            index -= 1
            a,i,ca = A[index]
            if size == 1:
                if a == S: yield [i]
                continue
            c0 = A[index-size][2] if index>size else 0
            if ca-c0 < S: break
            subS = S-a
            if subS in failedSums: continue # known unreachable sum
            failed = True
            for result in subSumForSize(subS,A[:index],size-1,failedSums):
                yield result+[i]
                failed = False
            if failed: failedSums.add(subS)

    if not A: return
    if S < 0: S,A = -S,[-a for a in A] # must have positive target
    offset = max(0,-min(A)) # circumvent negatives (requires loop on sizes)
    A      = sorted([(a+offset,i) for i,a in enumerate(A)])
    cumA   = accumulate(a for a,i in A)
    A      = [(a,i,ca) for (a,i),ca in zip(A,cumA)]

    if maxSize is None:
        maxSize = next((sz for sz,ca in enumerate(cumA) if ca > S),len(A))
    maxSize = min(len(A),maxSize)

    for a,_,_ in A[:smallSize]:
        newSums = [a+s for s in smallSums] + [a]
        smallSums.update(newSums)

    for size in range(1,maxSize+1):
        subS = S + offset*size
        for result in subSumForSize(subS,A,size):
            yield result
```

This function can then be used in another one that combines the lists with the required inversions and returns the indices back to their original lists.  By using the indices, we avoid any ambiguity on which list the elements originally belonged to.

```
def iCommonSumIndexes(A,B):
    for solution in iSubSumIndexes(0,[-a for a in A]+B):
        iA = [i for i in solution if i < len(A)]
        iB = [i-len(A) for i in solution if i >= len(A)]
        yield iA,iB
```

To use this, you will need to process indices from the output, rather than actual values, but this is a simple indirection easily done in a list comprehension.  The side benefit is that you can use the indices to map more complex objects that contain the values (e.g. accounting transactions):

```
listA = [455, 698, 756, 3,56, -9]
listB = [526,55,943,156,531,304,618,911,598,498,268,926,899,898,131,966,303,936,509,67,976,639,74,935,23,226,422,280,64,975,583,596,583]

for iA,iB in iCommonSumIndexes(listA,listB):
    sA = [listA[i] for i in iA]
    sB = [listB[i] for i in iB]
    print(sum(sA),sA,sB)

1454 [698, 756] [526, 226, 422, 280]
1454 [698, 756] [156, 304, 498, 74, 422]
1510 [698, 756, 56] [526, 156, 268, 74, 422, 64]
1510 [698, 756, 56] [526, 498, 422, 64]
1454 [698, 756] [156, 422, 280, 596]
754 [698, 56] [268, 422, 64]
1510 [698, 756, 56] [598, 268, 74, 226, 280, 64]
1510 [698, 756, 56] [156, 618, 598, 74, 64]
756 [756] [618, 74, 64]
...
```

The function returns every possible combination of indices that produce a common sum.  This includes combinations of elements in one list that give a total of zero and thus match an empty subset in the other list.

You can filter the output if you only want:

- unique value combinations
- distinct left/right patterns
- non-empty subsets.

The new strategy is to find a solution using increasing fixed set sizes.  In other words, find a 1-item solution, then a 2-item solution, then a 3-item solution, and so on.  Using this solution size loop allows a special conversion of items in the list to make them all positive.  This, in turn, allows use of a binary search to limit the number of values to evaluate.

The logic proceeds backward in a sorted array of values which allows memoizing failed partial sums for subsequent passes.  In addition to this, all possible sums of the first 20 elements are generated and take part in the memoizing optimization.  Those are the leaves of the search tree, so keeping them in memory has the most impact on overall performance.

A side benefit of the size loop approach is that the first solution is always a subset with the smallest number of values.  It also makes it easy to set a maximum size which will directly reduce the response time.

Another benefit of the new approach is that it is not limited to integer values. It can process floats provided that they have a non periodic binary representation (if not, the function could be adjusted to do some rounding or you can use a decimal data type).

The progressive solution size algorithm was also used to create a variant of the function that will find subsets with a given average. This variant implements a rounding option that could be used as an example.  See the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57172124/5237560)